# Subjective and objective case?

Tags: pronouns, subjects

Is it correct to say

> I am faster than him at swimming

Or

> I am faster than he at swimming

I've heard that the first sentence is wrong because you can't compare the subjective case with the objective case. Can someone clarify this for me?

Comment: Sorry, i dont think i get it

Comment: In modern grammar, "than" is treated as a preposition like "with" that can take an object pronoun/accusative case. So the first sentence is fine. "Than" can also take a reduced clause like the second sentence that takes "he" but that version would be too formal/unusual in modern English.

Comment: "I am faster than he **is**."

Comment: Forgetting how 'than' is analysed to fit in with accepted usage, accepted usage is 'I am faster than him' but 'I am faster than he is'. Acceptable English often doesn't conform to neat rules / patterns.